# Area of Square possibility

Tags: area

***The area of a square is given to be equal to $x^6 \pm x^5 \pm x^4 \pm x^3 \pm x^2 \pm x  \pm 1$. Is such an area possible such that it would be equal to a whole number??? If yes, what would be an expression for the area???***
 I do not have any idea how to approach the problem.
*Please Help.*
*Thankyou.*

Comment: The area of a square has to be a, err, square value.  Can that $x^6 \pm x^5 \pm x^4 \pm x^3 \pm x^2 \pm x  \pm 1$ be expressed as $y^2$ for some $y$?

Comment: Sure. Take $y = \sqrt{x^6 \pm x^5 \pm x^4 \pm x^3 \pm x^2 \pm x  \pm 1}$.

Comment: @fleablood  Yes but how can we tell if this expression is a square value??

Comment: @MPW I think the question means can we express it as the square of some other expression.

Comment: D'oh@  MPW has it of course.  In the real numbers all non-negative numbers have square roots so as long as $x^6 \pm x^5 \pm x^4 \pm x^3 \pm x^2 \pm x  \pm 1$ is non-negative you can.  Ignore my comment.  I was hinting at trying to factor.  But you don't need to be able to factor.  That was a brain fart on my part.

Comment: @fleablood Can we factor it???

Comment: @fleablood An edit: If it is a possible area, then what is the area (i.e. what would be a suitable expression for such an area.)?????

Comment: I don't know.  I don't think so.  But we don't have to.

If we could it'd be $(x^3 + something + 1)^2$ so we'd get some equation for the something.

BUT WE DON'T HAVE TO!

Comment: Writing the square root is a suitable expression.  The only condition is that $x^6 >= \mp x^5 \mp x^4 \mp x^3 \mp x^2 \mp x  \mp 1$

Comment: @fleablood I don't understand. Does this mean that such an expression for area is possible only if $x^6>=∓x^5∓x^4∓x^3∓x^2∓x∓1$

Comment: ^ The area of a square must be non-negative. So $x^6 \ge -(\text{The other terms})$

Comment: Well, you can't factor it if the last term is -1.  But as there are infinite possible values for x that will yield a positive value with the last term -1, such an expression doesn't reflect all answers.

Comment: @fleablood Only integer values should equal the expression for area. I didn't mention it before but has added it now to the question. :(

Comment: Try to factorise it...

Comment: @tatan what should we factorise?? Should we first come up with a square expression with unity coefficients??

Comment: @AbhijithS.Raj-See..it should come as a perfect square if it is a possible area of a square..

Comment: @tatan Is it possible to come up with such an expression that has only plus or minus unity coefficients and is also a perfect square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a family of solutions with the integers $(a,b)$.  Take the quadratic number $x=a+b \sqrt m$ where $a,b,m\in\mathbb Z$; $m$ square-free. If you want to restrict $x$ to be real  you have to make $m>0$, of course. Hence we have
$$ x=a+b \sqrt m$$  $$x^2=A_2+B_2\sqrt m$$ $$x^3=A_3+B_3\sqrt m$$ $$.......$$ $$x^6=A_6+B_6\sqrt m$$ All solution of 
$\pm b\pm B_2\pm B_3\pm B_4\pm B_5+ B_6=0$ gives a couple $(a,b)$ with $$\pm a\pm A_2\pm A_3\pm A_4\pm A_5+ A_6\pm 1$$ for which one has 
$$x^6\pm x^5\pm x^4\pm x^3\pm x^2\pm x\pm 1$$ is an integer.You must discard the solutions for which this integer is negative.

Similar way can be tried, (more difficult to manipulated obviously if degree greater than $2$) for $x$ algebraic number.

Answer (score 2):

For each choice of $\pm$, $x^6 \pm x^5 \pm \ldots \pm 1$ is a continuous function and unbounded above.  By the Intermediate Value Theorem it takes every real value $\ge 1$, including the squares of all nonzero integers.

It would be a more interesting question if you required $x$ to be an integer, or at least rational.
According to Maple, each of the curves $x^6  \pm x^5 \pm \ldots \pm 1 - y^2$ has genus $2$.  By [Faltings's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faltings%27s_theorem), they have only finitely many rational solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some I found with a brute force search.

$1+7+7^2-7^3-7^4+7^5+7^6==363^2$
$1+9-9^2+9^3-9^4-9^5+9^6==683^2$
$1-3-3^2-3^3+3^4-3^5+3^6==23^2$
$-1-2+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5+2^6==11^2$
$-1-2-2^2+2^3-2^4+2^5+2^6==9^2$
$-1-2-2^2+2^3+2^4-2^5+2^6==7^2$
$-1-2+2^2+2^3-2^4-2^5+2^6==5^2$
$-1-2+2^2-2^3-2^4-2^5+2^6==3^2$
$-1-2-2^2-2^3-2^4-2^5+2^6==1^2$

Mathematica code

```
Select[Flatten[Table[With[{gg = Total[((-1)^# & /@ IntegerDigits[pp, 2, 7])
Table[x^n, {n, 0, 6}]]}, {IntegerQ[Sqrt[gg]], gg, pp, x }], {pp, 0,
 127}, {x, 2, 20}], 1], First[#] == True &]
```

Fifth powers have two general solutions.

$1 - (n^2 -1) + (n^2 -1)^2 + (n^2 -1)^3 - (n^2 -1)^4 + (n^2 -1)^5 == (n(3 - 3 n^2 + n^4))^2$
$-1 - (n^2 +1) - (n^2 +1)^2 + (n^2 +1)^3 + (n^2 +1)^4 + (n^2 +1)^5 == (n(3 + 3 n^2 + n^4))^2$

Seventh powers have two general solutions.

$ 1 - (n^2 - 1) + (n^2 - 1)^2 - (n^2 - 1)^3 - (n^2 - 1)^4 + (n^2 - 1)^5 - (n^2 - 1)^6 + (n^2 - 1)^7 == (n (-4 + 6 n^2 - 4 n^4 + n^6))^2$

$-1 - (n^2 + 1) - (n^2 + 1)^2 - (n^2 + 1)^3 + (n^2 + 1)^4 + (n^2 + 1)^5 + (n^2 + 1)^6 + (n^2 + 1)^7 == (n (4 + 6 n^2 + 4 n^4 + n^6))^2$

If there is a general solution for power 6, it will likely be findable by a study of the solutions, but so far the solutions seem to be sporadic.

Comment: You are just awesome. I too ran it in mathematica and saw what happened. Thankyou very much.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  None of those are factorable as a polynomial.

Comment: @fleablood Yes I see you are right.

Comment: @EdPegg Yes this is right. But it doesn't say that such an expression would be factorable as a perfect square.

Answer (score 1):

If x can be any real then $x^6 \pm x^5 \pm x^4 \pm x^3 \pm x^2 \pm x  \pm 1$ = $\sqrt{x^6 \pm x^5 \pm x^4 \pm x^3 \pm x^2 \pm x  \pm 1}$ and the only criterion is the almost trivial $x^6 >= - other terms.

If x must be a positive integer or the length must be rational or some such requirement
that $x^6 \pm x^5 \pm x^4 \pm x^3 \pm x^2 \pm x  \pm 1$ must be factorable. The $x^6 \pm x^5 \pm x^4 \pm x^3 \pm x^2 \pm x  \pm 1$ = $(x^2 + something \pm 1)^2$.  Then you have $something^2 + 2*something =  \pm x^5 \pm x^4 \pm x^3 \pm x^2 \pm x  $.  Well this is impossible for variable x (as the highest power would need to be even).

Perhaps the simplest answer is $2^6 - 2^5 - 2^4 - 2^3 -2^2 - 2^1 - 1 = 1$.

====

Ah.  I see if we specify that x and the area must both be integers how can we find all answers?  Well that's a very interesting question....

Comment: But can x^6 - x^5 - x^4 - x^3 - x^2 - x - 1 be factorized as perfect square??

Comment: x need not be an integer or whole number. It should be a real number but the area should be a whole number.

Comment: If x is a real number then every polynomial with a positive leading term is unbounded and pass through infinitely many square integers.  Solve 1 + x + x^2 + .... + x^5 + x^6 =4 is difficult and maybe it isn't expressible but s solution definitely exists.